# Connecting 5V Joystick to Beagle Bone Black

Tags: beaglebone-black

I was recently trying to connect an simple analog joystick to test the ADC values being read by my Beagle Bone Black.

Since range of analog input for BBB is 0 to 1.8 V I supplied 1.8 V to the 5 V Joystick, but when I was trying to read the values it wasn't giving the expected values.

What do I do to get proper values?

Comment: *"it wasn't giving the expected values"* Are we supposed to know what that means? You have provided almost no information for us to help you. The resistance of the pots would be a great start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First open up the joystick to see if it has circuitry in it and not just potentiometers. If it has circuitry then that requires 5V and it won't work properly without it.
2. If it has circuitry, be sure the output is what you think it is. You are expecting a DC voltage but some joystick systems output a digital signal. Look at the output on a scope.
3. If it in fact it does output 0 to 5 VDC then simply put a voltage divider using 2 resistors each on the X and Y outputs. Typical values can be calculated easily or use a web calculator like this one:
   http://www.raltron.com/cust/tools/voltage_divider.asp
   Best of Luck.